# Completar valores em uma tabela, com valores da própria tabela?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, pandas

Eu tenho a tabela

```
    data        ativo   valor     ajuste       arquivo
17/07/2020  teste1  4,35       nan       9032800000190015197.txt
16/07/2020  teste1  nan        nan       9032800000190015197.txt
15/07/2020  teste1  3,12       nan       9032800000190015197.txt
14/07/2020  teste1  nan        nan       9032800000190015197.txt
13/07/2020  teste1  nan       6367.55    9032800000190015197.txt
17/07/2020  teste2  3,7     -1462.825    9032800000190015197.txt
16/07/2020  teste2  nan        nan       9032800000190015197.txt
15/07/2020  teste2  nan        nan       9032800000190015197.txt
14/07/2020  teste2  nan      -235.825    9032800000190015197.txt
13/07/2020  teste2  nan        nan       9032800000190015197.txt
17/07/2020  teste3  5          nan       9032800000190015197.txt
16/07/2020  teste3  nan        nan       9032800000190015197.txt
15/07/2020  teste3  6,7        nan       9032800000190015197.txt
14/07/2020  teste3  nan        nan       9032800000190015197.txt
13/07/2020  teste3  nan        nan       9032800000190015197.txt
```

e preciso obter o seguinte resultado

```
   date        ativo   valor     ajuste       arquivo
17/07/2020  teste1  4,35       nan       9032800000190015197.txt
16/07/2020  teste1  4,35       nan       9032800000190015197.txt
15/07/2020  teste1  3,12       nan       9032800000190015197.txt
14/07/2020  teste1  3,12       nan       9032800000190015197.txt
13/07/2020  teste1  3,12      6367.55    9032800000190015197.txt
17/07/2020  teste2  3,7     -1462.825    9032800000190015197.txt
16/07/2020  teste2  3,7        nan       9032800000190015197.txt
15/07/2020  teste2  3,7        nan       9032800000190015197.txt
14/07/2020  teste2  3,7      -235.825    9032800000190015197.txt
13/07/2020  teste2  3,7        nan       9032800000190015197.txt
17/07/2020  teste3  5          nan       9032800000190015197.txt
16/07/2020  teste3  5          nan       9032800000190015197.txt
15/07/2020  teste3  6,7        nan       9032800000190015197.txt
14/07/2020  teste3  6,7        nan       9032800000190015197.txt
13/07/2020  teste3  6,7        nan       9032800000190015197.txt
```

Tenho valores ausentes no campo **valor** e preciso preencher com os valores anteriores da mesma tabela, considerando que o **valor** deve ser do mesmo **ativo** e **data** mais baixo. E o valor não é o mais alto nem o mais baixo, mas sim o do dia anterior que tem um valor diferente de zero.

Não consegui uma solução que atendesse a essas condições. Alguém tem ideia de como fazer? Usando *pandas.DataFrame.backfill*, não consegui.

Tentei em SQL, e não consegui, fiz esse código

```
select a.dt_data, a.co_ativo,
nullif(a.vr_valor, (select b.vr_valor from tabela b 
where b.co_ativo = a.co_ativo and b.dt_data between '2020-07-01' and '2020-07-31' and b.vr_valor is not null order by b.dt_data desc limit 1))
from tabela a
where a.dt_data between '2020-07-01' and '2020-07-31'
order by a.dt_data desc
```

sem exito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível fazer essa substituição fazendo o agrupamento por ativo com a função [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) juntamente com o [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html), desta forma:

```
df['data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['data'], dayfirst=True)
df.sort_values(['ativo', 'data'], ascending = [True,False], inplace = True)

df['valor'] = df.groupby(['ativo'])['valor'].ffill()
#ou df = df.assign(valor = df.groupby(['ativo'])['valor'].ffill())
#resultado
    data        ativo   valor
0   2020-07-17  teste1  4,35
1   2020-07-16  teste1  4,35
2   2020-07-15  teste1  3,12
3   2020-07-14  teste1  3,12
4   2020-07-13  teste1  3,12
5   2020-07-17  teste2  3,7
6   2020-07-16  teste2  3,7
7   2020-07-15  teste2  3,7
8   2020-07-14  teste2  3,7
9   2020-07-13  teste2  3,7
10  2020-07-17  teste3  5
11  2020-07-16  teste3  5
12  2020-07-15  teste3  6,7
13  2020-07-14  teste3  6,7
14  2020-07-13  teste3  6,7
```

---

### Editado

Usando a nova amostragem de dados, o código ainda da a saída esperada:

```
    s = io.StringIO("""    data        ativo   valor     ajuste       arquivo
17/07/2020  teste1  4,35       nan       9032800000190015197.txt
16/07/2020  teste1  nan        nan       9032800000190015197.txt
15/07/2020  teste1  3,12       nan       9032800000190015197.txt
14/07/2020  teste1  nan        nan       9032800000190015197.txt
13/07/2020  teste1  nan       6367.55    9032800000190015197.txt
17/07/2020  teste2  3,7     -1462.825    9032800000190015197.txt
16/07/2020  teste2  nan        nan       9032800000190015197.txt
15/07/2020  teste2  nan        nan       9032800000190015197.txt
14/07/2020  teste2  nan      -235.825    9032800000190015197.txt
13/07/2020  teste2  nan        nan       9032800000190015197.txt
17/07/2020  teste3  5          nan       9032800000190015197.txt
16/07/2020  teste3  nan        nan       9032800000190015197.txt
15/07/2020  teste3  6,7        nan       9032800000190015197.txt
14/07/2020  teste3  nan        nan       9032800000190015197.txt
13/07/2020  teste3  nan        nan       9032800000190015197.txt
    """)

df = pd.read_csv(s, sep="\s\s+")

df['data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['data'], dayfirst=True)
df.sort_values(['ativo', 'data'], ascending = [True,False], inplace = True)
df['valor'] = df.groupby(['ativo'])['valor'].ffill()
df.head(20)

    data        ativo   valor   ajuste      arquivo
0   2020-07-17  teste1  4,35    NaN         9032800000190015197.txt
1   2020-07-16  teste1  4,35    NaN         9032800000190015197.txt
2   2020-07-15  teste1  3,12    NaN         9032800000190015197.txt
3   2020-07-14  teste1  3,12    NaN         9032800000190015197.txt
4   2020-07-13  teste1  3,12    6367.550    9032800000190015197.txt
5   2020-07-17  teste2  3,7     -1462.825   9032800000190015197.txt
6   2020-07-16  teste2  3,7     NaN         9032800000190015197.txt
7   2020-07-15  teste2  3,7     NaN         9032800000190015197.txt
8   2020-07-14  teste2  3,7     -235.825    9032800000190015197.txt
9   2020-07-13  teste2  3,7     NaN         9032800000190015197.txt
10  2020-07-17  teste3  5       NaN         9032800000190015197.txt
11  2020-07-16  teste3  5       NaN         9032800000190015197.txt
12  2020-07-15  teste3  6,7     NaN         9032800000190015197.txt
13  2020-07-14  teste3  6,7     NaN         9032800000190015197.txt
14  2020-07-13  teste3  6,7     NaN         9032800000190015197.txt
```

Comment: Obrigado Terry, pela contribuição. Reproduzindo o código no meu data frame, não executou as substituições isso se deve ao fato de que tenho mais colunas no arquivo?

Comment: @Kabelo Ter mais colunas não deveria ser um problema. No seu DF a coluna **data** já estava no formato de `Date`? Porque se ela já estava isso pode dar o retorno errado

Comment: Tambem adicionei uma outra opção usando `assign` para retornar os valores preenchidos para a coluna `valor`. Se você puder testar :)

Comment: Caso o problema persista, vou pedir para você modificar seus dados de teste disponíveis na pergunta para que eu consiga reproduzir na minha máquina o que esta acontecendo com você. Usando os dados que você disponibilizou até agora, a minha saída esta igual a forma como você esperava como correta

Comment: Inseri as colunas que tenho no arquivo com os mesmos tipos de dados. Não funcionou essa alternativa.

Comment: @Kabelo Para mim o código continua funcionando, dando a saída esperada.

Comment: Terry, funcionou, cara!! restart no kernel aqui e rolou!!Muito obrigado!!!